# How to make 2 multiplications with js on a single html page

Tags: javascript

I want to make 2 multiplications on the same html page with js. Like there is a multiplication box, I want to make another one. This is my code

```
var a = document.getElementById("a");
var b = document.getElementById("b");
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var xstored = a.getAttribute("data-in");
var ystored = b.getAttribute("data-in");

setInterval(function(){
    if( a == document.activeElement ){
        var temp = a.value;
        if( xstored != temp ){
            xstored = temp;
            a.setAttribute("data-in",temp);
            calculate();
        }
    }
    if( b == document.activeElement ){
        var temp = b.value;
        if( ystored != temp ){
            ystored = temp;
            b.setAttribute("data-in",temp);
            calculate();
        }
    }
},50);

function calculate(){
    c.innerHTML = a.value * b.value;
}

a.onblur = calculate;
calculate();
```

So this is my code...

And I want to make 2 of this code but I would replace

```
 a --> d
 b --> e
 c --> f
```

But it doesn't work...

Help please !

Thanks

Comment: You already know about functions, what about putting the current code inside one that takes 3 arguments which are the 3 elements (`a`, `b` and `c`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make `calculate()` accept three arguments so it can do the calculation with any three elements.

```
function calculate(input1, input2, output) {
    output.innerHTML = input1.value * input2.value;
}

calculate(a, b, c);
calculate(d, e, f);
```

Edit: a more complete picture. Use `getElementById` and `getAttribute` like you were to set all your variables. I've made some assumptions that you want to repeat everything you've done with `a` and `b` for `d` and `e`. You should really use variable names that have more semantic meaning.

```
// Get all your elements stores
var a, b, c, d, e, f;
var astored, bstored, dstored, estored;

function calculate(input1, input2, output) {
    output.innerHTML = input1.value * input2.value;
}

setInterval(function(){
    var temp;

    if (a == document.activeElement) {
        temp = a.value;
        if (astored != temp){
            astored = temp;
            a.setAttribute("data-in",temp);
            calculate(a, b, c);
        }
    } else if (b == document.activeElement) {
        temp = b.value;
        if (bstored != temp) {
            bstored = temp;
            b.setAttribute("data-in",temp);
            calculate(a, b, c);
        }
    } else if (d == document.activeElement) {
        temp = d.value;
        if (dstored != temp) {
            dstored = temp;
            d.setAttribute("data-in",temp);
            calculate(d, e, f);
        }
    } else if (e == document.activeElement) {
        temp = e.value;
        if (estored != temp) {
            estored = temp;
            e.setAttribute("data-in",temp);
            calculate(d, e, f);
        }
    }
}, 50);

a.onblur = calculate(a, b, c);
b.onblur = calculate(a, b, c);
d.onblur = calculate(d, e, f);
e.onblur = calculate(d, e, f);
calculate(a, b, c);
calculate(d, e, f);
```

Comment: Where should I put this code ? Like I keep the old one and I add that to the end of the code ?? Thanks for your reply and BTW I am a beginner so I need help ! Can you just edit my code and post it here so I can copy and paste it and I will tell you if it works !

Comment: I you want to know why I ask that go and check my website : http://www.touficapks.ml/seconds I did the js code for the years and I want to make the same for months

Comment: You can just replace your current `calculate` function with this. The code you wrote for `a`, `b`, and `c` you need to repeat for `d`, `e`, `f`. You need to get those elements and you can pass them into the new function like I've shown.

Comment: Did you call the function with the three arguments? If you just replaced the function, the function is expecting the three elements to do the calculation. You can't call it just by `calculate();` you need to provide three arguments like so `caclulate(a, b, c)`. See my recent update.

Comment: I'll copy your code and I will tell you what will happen !

Comment: I copied it and pasted it into my scripts.js but it doesn't work !! Have you seen the website ?

Comment: See the source of the html on the website and the js is located at : http://www.touficapks.ml/seconds/js/scripts.js

Comment: I've seen the website. Did you set all the variables correctly?

Comment: Yes ! And BTW I will make h,i,j for the days...

Comment: Do you see where the problem is ? Thanks

Comment: You haven't set the variables correctly. Please read the beginning of the edit - you still need to set a, b, c, d, e, f and the stored variables with document.getElementById and getAttribute.

Comment: What should the code look like ?

Comment: Exactly like you had it in your original post, you just need to repeat it for d, e, f. Instead of xstored and ystored, I made the astored, bstored, dstored, and estored.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service - you can't expect people to write entire programs for you to just copy and paste.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I am a beginner and I don't know too much about JS. So, I have my original code and I just add the one you created ?

Comment: Ohhhb now I understand !! Thanks for your help

Comment: It works for everything now ! Thanks. I like you, keep helping people as much as you can !!

Comment: You are welcome. The goal is to help teach you, not just give you something to copy and paste. I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: Can you help me with another thing ? I will open a new question...

Comment: I opened the new question ! Go see it...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37191715/5922162 Can you help with that ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is my new code with h, i, j. Thanks!

```
// Get all your elements stores
var a = document.getElementById("a");
var b = document.getElementById("b");
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var d = document.getElementById("d");
var e = document.getElementById("e");
var f = document.getElementById("f");
var h = document.getElementById("h");
var i = document.getElementById("i");
var j = document.getElementById("j");
var astored = a.getAttribute("data-in");
var bstored = b.getAttribute("data-in");
var dstored = d.getAttribute("data-in");
var estored = e.getAttribute("data-in");
var hstored = h.getAttribute("data-in");
var istored = i.getAttribute("data-in");

function calculate(input1, input2, output) {
    output.innerHTML = input1.value * input2.value;
}

setInterval(function(){
    var temp;

    if (a == document.activeElement) {
        temp = a.value;
        if (astored != temp){
            astored = temp;
            a.setAttribute("data-in",temp);
            calculate(a, b, c);
        }
    } else if (b == document.activeElement) {
        temp = b.value;
        if (bstored != temp) {
            bstored = temp;
            b.setAttribute("data-in",temp);
            calculate(a, b, c);
        }
    } else if (d == document.activeElement) {
        temp = d.value;
        if (dstored != temp) {
            dstored = temp;
            d.setAttribute("data-in",temp);
            calculate(d, e, f);
        }
    } else if (e == document.activeElement) {
        temp = e.value;
        if (estored != temp) {
            estored = temp;
            e.setAttribute("data-in",temp);
            calculate(d, e, f);
        }
    } else if (h == document.activeElement) {
        temp = h.value;
        if (hstored != temp) {
            hstored = temp;
            h.setAttribute("data-in",temp);
            calculate(h, i, j);
        }
    } else if (i == document.activeElement) {
        temp = i.value;
        if (istored != temp) {
            istored = temp;
            i.setAttribute("data-in",temp);
            calculate(h, i, j);
        }
    }
}, 50);

a.onblur = calculate(a, b, c);
b.onblur = calculate(a, b, c);
d.onblur = calculate(d, e, f);
e.onblur = calculate(d, e, f);
h.onblur = calculate(h, i, j);
i.onblur = calculate(h, i, j);
calculate(a, b, c);
calculate(d, e, f);
calculate(h, i, j);
```