# How to add 3 results with js?

Tags: javascript, addition

How to add 3 results with js ? I mean I have 3 calculators and I got a result from each one. How to combine them into one result ? Like if one is 3 and another is 7 it would get me : 10 l. But the 3 and the 7 are the result of other multiplications... For me I have to calculate the c + f + j. Here is my code :

```
var a = document.getElementById("a");
var b = document.getElementById("b");
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var d = document.getElementById("d");
var e = document.getElementById("e");
var f = document.getElementById("f");
var h = document.getElementById("h");
var i = document.getElementById("i");
var j = document.getElementById("j");
var astored = a.getAttribute("data-in");
var bstored = b.getAttribute("data-in");
var dstored = d.getAttribute("data-in");
var estored = e.getAttribute("data-in");
var hstored = h.getAttribute("data-in");
var istored = i.getAttribute("data-in");

function calculate(input1, input2, output) {
    output.innerHTML = input1.value * input2.value;
}

setInterval(function(){
    var temp;

    if (a == document.activeElement) {
        temp = a.value;
        if (astored != temp){
            astored = temp;
            a.setAttribute("data-in",temp);
            calculate(a, b, c);
        }
    } else if (b == document.activeElement) {
        temp = b.value;
        if (bstored != temp) {
            bstored = temp;
            b.setAttribute("data-in",temp);
            calculate(a, b, c);
        }
    } else if (d == document.activeElement) {
        temp = d.value;
        if (dstored != temp) {
            dstored = temp;
            d.setAttribute("data-in",temp);
            calculate(d, e, f);
        }
    } else if (e == document.activeElement) {
        temp = e.value;
        if (estored != temp) {
            estored = temp;
            e.setAttribute("data-in",temp);
            calculate(d, e, f);
        }
    } else if (h == document.activeElement) {
        temp = h.value;
        if (hstored != temp) {
            hstored = temp;
            h.setAttribute("data-in",temp);
            calculate(h, i, j);
        }
    } else if (i == document.activeElement) {
        temp = i.value;
        if (istored != temp) {
            istored = temp;
            i.setAttribute("data-in",temp);
            calculate(h, i, j);
        }
    }
}, 50);

a.onblur = calculate(a, b, c);
b.onblur = calculate(a, b, c);
d.onblur = calculate(d, e, f);
e.onblur = calculate(d, e, f);
h.onblur = calculate(h, i, j);
i.onblur = calculate(h, i, j);
calculate(a, b, c);
calculate(d, e, f);
calculate(h, i, j);
```

Comment: You can simply add three results exactly how you mentioned in Javascript: `var result = c + f + j;`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek It doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a new function called sum_stuff:

```
function sum_stuff(input1, input2, input3, output) {
    output.innerHTML = parseInt( input1.innerHTML ) + parseInt( input2.innerHTML ) + parseInt( input3.innerHTML );
}
```

and call it like:

```
sum_stuff(c, f, j, elem_to_print_into);
```

and the `elem_to_print_into` is another input field

Comment: It gives me NaN ! I created the function sum_stuff (I named it add) and I called it add(c, f, j, elem_to_print_into); but it doesn't work at all ! And in the HTML I added <div id="elem_to_print_into"></div>. BTW I need that for my website : http://www.touficapks.ml/seconds. The JS is at : http://www.touficapks.ml/seconds/js/scripts.js. I need to add the years to the months to the days... Thanks for helping

Comment: try by putting the add(c, f, j, elem_to_print_into); call right at the end of the setInterval's internal function, after the last else, because right now the add function is called only once, when the page is initialized, so obviously it is not able to compute anything

Comment: Okk I'll try, have you seen the website ?

Comment: yes, I wrote the above explanation based on what I saw on the site. I didn't respond yesterday because *What's wrong with my code ?? It doesn't work* without anything to look at is not very informative

Comment: Where do you mean after the last else ?? Is that good ? (See the js on the website)

Comment: Yes, that's a good place. I've updated the code of the function. Use that, because c, f and j are divs, not inputs so they don't have the value property

Comment: Yay it works !! But can I change the : You lived <div id="c"></div> + <div id="f"></div> + <div id="j"></div>seconds ! by You lived <div id="elem_to_print_into"></div> ??

Comment: Ohh no I can't but I have found a solution ! I made the divs for c, f and j hidden and added the elem_to_print_into... Thanks a lot for helping me !

Comment: You're welcome. Now please accept my answer as a sign of gratitude for my time :)

Comment: Okk I'll do but how ?

Comment: Like this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow